# msxml6.tlh IXMLDOMNode error incomplete type is not allowed from detected during instantiation of class

Tags: c++, msxml6

```
MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocumentPtr pXMLDom = NULL;

HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
hr = pXMLDom.CreateInstance("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0");
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    printf("Failed to instantiate an XML DOM.\n");
    return NULL;
}

if (pXMLDom->load(L"dynaDOMsmart.xml") == VARIANT_TRUE) 
{
    printf("XML DOM loaded from dynaDOMsmart.xml:\n%s\n", (LPCSTR)pXMLDom->xml);
    return pXMLDom;
}
else
{
    // Failed to load xml
    printf("Failed to load DOM from dynaDOMsmart.xml. %s\n",
        (LPCSTR)pXMLDom->parseError->Getreason());
}
```

From a Windows Form Project in C++, I'm trying to load an `IXMLDOMDocument` using                  the `MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocumentPtr pxmlDomDoc` variable. I am getting this error:

> incomplete type is not allowed

detected during instantiation of the class.

I dont know why it's occurring, since I did it the same way from a console project in the same language without error.

Comment: The title of the question looks fishy.  Do *not* #include msxml6.tlh, use `#import <msxml6.dll>` instead.

Comment: FYI, on a side note, both of your `LPCSTR` type casts are wrong. `LPCSTR` is an alias for `const cbar*`, but `xml` and `reason` are both `BSTR` (`wchar_t*`) instead. You CA T cast wide strings into narrow strings like this. But, you can have `printf` print out wide strings.